# Regex, sublime-syntax file, matching all after a particular character except a specific group

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, sublime-syntax

I have a new file extension with a specific syntax, i've created a sublime-syntax file, and i'm trying to highlight certain characters in sublime text editor..

Assuming the following text :

```
Accept-Language: en-EN
n1.legend=0,1,meta,text,Legend,b1,30 chars max
r1.label=Contain
```

I want to match all characters after ":" or "=" except the letter "b" followed by one or two numbers (like a placeholder). I tried the following regex :

```
(?<=[=|:])((?!b[0-9]{1,2}).)*
```

It works but it doesn't match characters after the "b1" for instance ",30 chars max", why is that ? any help please ? i'm not an expert in regex..

Problem capture :

[image: Sublime tes syntax file]

> ",30 chars max" must be yellow..

Comment: You are asserting either a `:` or `=` to the left followed by repeating matching any char until you encounter b followed by a digit. The regex can not match what comes after b1 because there is no `:` or `=` after it.

Comment: @The fourth bird, Ahh ok i see.. i will reflect upon a solution, if you or any one could propose a correction, i will be grateful..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the matches only (and if supported) you could make use of `\G` to get repetitive matches  and `\K` to clear the match buffer.

```
(?:^[^=:\r\n]+[=:]|\G(?!^))(?:b\d{1,2})?\K.*?(?=b\d{1,2}|$)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `^[^=:\r\n]+[=:]` Match either the pattern that starts the string
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the positive at the previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `(?:b\d{1,2})?` Optionally match b followed by 2 digits
- `\K` Reset the match buffer
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible (non greedy)
- `(?=b\d{1,2}|$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is either b followed by 2 digits or end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UXTBOJ/1)

Comment: Oh man, thanks @The fourth bird, it works :), it's been 3 days know trying to solve this issue.. just to mention i removed the first "^" sign to get exactly what i want, if i keep it, it will match also what's before the equal sign..

Comment: Done :), i didn't know it.. i'm not aware of the all stackoverflow instructions.. thanks for reminding me @The fourth bird

Answer (score 0):

If from the line `0,1,meta,text,Legend,1,30 chars max` you want to match `0,1,meta,text,Legend,,30 chars max` then the following regex should suit your needs:

```
=(.*)b\d{1,2}(.*)
```

Concatenating the first and second match groups (replace string `$1$2`) gives you your match.

[RegExr demo](https://regexr.com/52qni)

Comment: Thanks @simon-pearson.. Yes it works for this specific line, but it doesn't for the whole.. how to get : (en-EN)
(0,1,meta,text,Legend,,30 chars max)
(Contain) i will add an image to clarify my idea..